# Passing a varying list of tuples as a parameter to a spark udf in scala, and returning single tuple

Tags: scala

I have an array of tuples as `[["10/12/2021", "(385) 683-7718", "23456", "abc@jkl.com"],["25/12/2021", "(678) 683-2354", "23456", "abc@jkl.com"]]`*(Note: all data are String type when passing)*. This array might contain 'n' elements with 'm' elements in each tuple. I want to create a udf which can take this array, apply some decision logic and return a single selected tuple based on that logic. For my case I want to return a tuple whichever have the recent date.
I applied this udf for that;

```
val tupleByDate = udf{my_array: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Row] =>
my_array.map(r => (r.getDate(0), r.getAs[String](1), r.getAs[Int](2), r.getAs[String](3), )).sortBy(_._1).take(1)}
```

But I am getting this error.
`error: No implicit Ordering defined for java.sql.Date.`

The **ideal solution** would be the one where I can receive any number of elements as tuple in the array. Use some logic to make my decision; logic may contain one or more condition. And based on the logic, return single tuple from array of tuples.

I am very new to scala, so can anyone help me on this.